# missing chunk number 0 for toast value 1086251 in pg_toast_2619

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Below log message is available in postgres log file several thousand times. How to resolve.

> missing chunk number 0 for toast value 815441 in pg_toast_2619.

pg_toast_2619 is the pg_statistic table. it (pg_statistic) contains duplicated records also. How to resolve this situation.  What is the reason behind this.

We are using Postgresq Database Version 9.2.

Comment: This's exactly question you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47533639/7925366).

Comment: Why and when this error will occur?