# SQL/PostgreSQL - Error observed in the QUERY not caught by the "EXCEPTION" block in the stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure to be used in a PostgreSQL DBMS.

The purpose of this stored procedure is to delete all records that present the following problem...

Query:

```
my_database=# SELECT file INTO my_file_now FROM public.my_datatable WHERE my_id='2fdf5297-8d4a-38bc-bb26-b8a4b7ba47ec';
ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for toast value 3483039 in pg_toast_3473493
```

Based on the above behavior I created the following stored procedure:

Stored procedure:

```
DO $f$
DECLARE
    my_file_now BYTEA;
    my_id_now UUID;
BEGIN
FOR my_id_now IN SELECT my_id FROM public.my_datatable LOOP
    BEGIN
        SELECT file
            INTO my_file_now
            FROM public.my_datatable WHERE my_id=my_id_now;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'CORRUPTED MY_ID - % ', my_id_now;
            DELETE FROM public.my_datatable WHERE my_id=my_id_now;
    END;
END LOOP;
END;
$f$;
```

**QUESTION:** Why is the error observed in the query not caught by the "EXCEPTION" block in the stored procedure?

Thanks! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our view there is really no reason for the block in "EXCEPTION" not to be executed. Sounds like a bug to us. We reported this to the PostgreSQL community in their mailing list ( pgsql-bugs@lists.postgresql.org ).

Given the impossibility of using the above stored procedure I created a bash script with a much, much more sophisticated approach (see below).

**Refers to the "CONFIGURATION SECTION" section for more information, to make your adjustments and test the bash script before applying changes to your table.**

The "CONFIGURATION SECTION" section is at the end of the script. At first it is sufficient only make adjustments to it.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# NOTE: Avoid problems with relative paths! By Questor
SCRIPTDIR_V="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

F_GET_STDERR_R=""
F_GET_STDOUT_R=""
F_GET_EXIT_CODE_R=0
f_get_stderr_stdout() {
    : 'Run a command and capture output from stderr, stdout and exit code

    Args:
        CMD_TO_EXEC (str): Command to be executed.

    Returns:
        F_GET_STDERR_R (str): Output to stderr.
        F_GET_STDOUT_R (str): Output to stdout.
        F_GET_EXIT_CODE_R (int): Exit code.
    '

    CMD_TO_EXEC=$1
    F_GET_STDERR_R=""
    F_GET_STDOUT_R=""
    unset t_std t_err t_ret
    eval "$( eval "$CMD_TO_EXEC" 2> >(t_err=$(cat); typeset -p t_err) > >(t_std=$(cat); typeset -p t_std); t_ret=$?; typeset -p t_ret )"
    F_GET_STDERR_R=$t_err
    F_GET_STDOUT_R=$t_std
    F_GET_EXIT_CODE_R=$t_ret
}

f_log_manager() {
    : 'Generate and manage output and error logs.

    Args:
        VALUE_TO_INSERT (str): Value to insert into log file.
        LOG_TYPE (Optional[int]): 0 - Output log; 1 - Error log. Default 0.
        CREATE_NEW_LOG (Optional[int]): 0 - Inserts into existing log file; 
    1 - Creates a new log file. Default 0.
        PATH_TO_LOG (Optional[str]): Folder path to create log file (without "/" 
    at the end). If empty, a new log file will be created in the current folder 
    (value in "SCRIPTDIR_V").
        VAL_INS_ON_SCREEN (Optional[int]): 0 - Will not print "VALUE_TO_INSERT" 
    on screen; 1 - Will print "VALUE_TO_INSERT" on screen. Default 0.
    '

    VALUE_TO_INSERT=$1
    LOG_TYPE=$2
    CREATE_NEW_LOG=$3
    PATH_TO_LOG=$4
    VAL_INS_ON_SCREEN=$5

    if [ -z "$LOG_TYPE" ] ; then
        LOG_TYPE=0
    fi
    if [ -z "$CREATE_NEW_LOG" ] ; then
        CREATE_NEW_LOG=0
    fi
    if [ -z "$PATH_TO_LOG" ] ; then
        PATH_TO_LOG="$SCRIPTDIR_V"
    fi
    if [ -z "$VAL_INS_ON_SCREEN" ] ; then
        VAL_INS_ON_SCREEN=0
    fi

    LOG_FILE_NAME=""
    case $LOG_TYPE in
        0)
            LOG_FILE_NAME="$PATH_TO_LOG/output.log"
        ;;
        1)
            LOG_FILE_NAME="$PATH_TO_LOG/error.log"
        ;;
    esac

    LOG_APPEND_OR_CREATE=""
    case $CREATE_NEW_LOG in
        0)
            LOG_APPEND_OR_CREATE=">>"
        ;;
        1)
            LOG_APPEND_OR_CREATE=">"
        ;;
    esac

    if [[ ${VAL_INS_ON_SCREEN} -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "$VALUE_TO_INSERT"
    fi

    eval "echo \"$VALUE_TO_INSERT\" $LOG_APPEND_OR_CREATE $LOG_FILE_NAME"
}

# NOTE: Will search across all table rows for corrupted records. Corrupted records 
# will be basically all records in which a field with a FILE ("BYTEA") cannot be 
# returned with its value. By Questor
f_chk_corrupted() {
    f_log_manager " > [chk_corrupted] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" 0 0 "" 1

    # NOTE: Get the number of records from the table. By Questor
    f_get_stderr_stdout "sudo -u postgres psql $TARGET_BASE -c \"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $TARGET_TABLE;\""

    TBL_ROWS_QUANTITY=$(echo "$F_GET_STDOUT_R" | sed '3!d')
    TBL_ROWS_QUANTITY="${TBL_ROWS_QUANTITY#"${TBL_ROWS_QUANTITY%%[![:space:]]*}"}"

    if [ ${TEST_MODE} -eq 1 ] ; then

        # NOTE: GOOD FOR TESTING BEFORE DELETING EFFECTIVELY. By Questor
        TBL_ROWS_QUANTITY=$T_MODE_ROWS

    fi

    for (( i=0; i<$TBL_ROWS_QUANTITY; i++ )); do
        f_log_manager " > [rom_pos: $i] ---------------------------" 0 0 "" 1

        # NOTE: Search the row for its position and test if the row has problems 
        # trying to retrieve the file field. By Questor
        f_get_stderr_stdout "sudo -u postgres psql $TARGET_BASE -c \"SELECT $TARGET_TABLE_FILE_FLD FROM $TARGET_TABLE LIMIT 1 OFFSET $i;\""

        if [[ ${F_GET_EXIT_CODE_R} -ne 0 ]] && [[ $F_GET_STDERR_R == *" chunk number "* ]]; then

            # NOTE: If the row has problems, then fetch the row by its position and 
            # retrieve the indicated id field. By Questor
            f_get_stderr_stdout "sudo -u postgres psql $TARGET_BASE -c \"SELECT $TARGET_TABLE_ID_FLD FROM $TARGET_TABLE LIMIT 1 OFFSET $i;\""

            # NOTE: Handle the output (id field) and insert input in the file 
            # "ids_corrpt_files.txt". The "ids_corrpt_files.txt" file has the rows 
            # that will be deleted according to the criteria. By Questor
            ID_CORRPT_FILE=$(echo "$F_GET_STDOUT_R" | sed '3!d')
            ID_CORRPT_FILE="${ID_CORRPT_FILE#"${ID_CORRPT_FILE%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
            echo "$ID_CORRPT_FILE" >> ids_corrpt_files.txt

            # NOTE: Corrupted row. Logging. By Questor
            f_log_manager "CORRUPTED --- $ID_CORRPT_FILE" 0 0 "" 1

        else

            # NOTE: NOT corrupted row . Logging. By Questor
            f_log_manager "UNCORRUPTED" 0 0 "" 1

        fi
        f_log_manager " < ---------------------------" 0 0 "" 1
    done
    f_log_manager " < [chk_corrupted] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" 0 0 "" 1
}

# NOTE: Delete the rows registered in the "ids_corrpt_files.txt" file in the previous step. By Questor
f_del_corrupted() {
    f_log_manager " > [f_del_corrupted] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" 0 0 "" 1
    while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]; do
        ID_CORRPT_FILE="$p"
        f_log_manager " > [id_file: $ID_CORRPT_FILE] ---------------------------" 0 0 "" 1

        if [ ${TEST_MODE} -eq 1 ] ; then

            # NOTE: GOOD FOR TESTING BEFORE DELETING EFFECTIVELY. By Questor
            f_get_stderr_stdout "sudo -u postgres psql $TARGET_BASE -c \"SELECT $TARGET_TABLE_ID_FLD FROM $TARGET_TABLE WHERE $TARGET_TABLE_ID_FLD='$ID_CORRPT_FILE';\""

        else

            # NOTE: Deleta a row. By Questor
            f_get_stderr_stdout "sudo -u postgres psql $TARGET_BASE -c \"DELETE FROM $TARGET_TABLE WHERE $TARGET_TABLE_ID_FLD='$ID_CORRPT_FILE';\""
        fi

        # NOTE: Logging on success or error. By Questor
        if [[ ${F_GET_EXIT_CODE_R} -ne 0 ]]; then
            f_log_manager "DELETED ----- ERROR" 0 0 "" 1
        else
            f_log_manager "DELETED ----- OK" 0 0 "" 1
        fi

        f_log_manager " < ---------------------------" 0 0 "" 1
    done < ids_corrpt_files.txt
    f_log_manager " < [f_del_corrupted] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" 0 0 "" 1
}

# NOTE: Remove log files from possible previous operations. By Questor
rm -f "/var/tmp/error.log"
rm -f "/var/tmp/output.log"

# NOTE: Remove file "ids_corrpt_files.txt" from possible previous operations. 
# By Questor
rm -f "./ids_corrpt_files.txt"

# NOTE: INFORM YOUR PARAMETERS IN THIS SECTION! By Questor
# > -----------------------------------------------------------------
# CONFIGURATION SECTION
# ---------------------------------

# IMPORTANT: This scrit DELETES UNRECOVERABLE RECORDS that have problems related 
# to "chunk number" ("toast value"). FIRST TRY TO EXECUTE PROCEDURES TO RECOVER 
# YOUR RECORDS AND EXECUTING THIS SCRIPT AS A LAST STEP IF NECESSARY! By Questor

# NOTE: Base with problematic table. By Questor
TARGET_BASE="my_database"

# NOTE: Problematic table . By Questor
TARGET_TABLE="my_table"

# NOTE: Problematic table ids. By Questor
TARGET_TABLE_ID_FLD="my_id"

# NOTE: Problematic file field name ("BYTEA"). By Questor
TARGET_TABLE_FILE_FLD="my_file"

# NOTE: IN TEST MODE YOU CAN CHECK CODE OPERATION WITH YOURS PARAMETERS WITHOUT 
# DELETING RECORDS/MODIFYING DATA. WE STRONGLY RECOMMEND USING THIS MODE FIRST 
# FOR TESTING! By Questor
TEST_MODE=1

# NOTE: How many rows you want to test in test mode. By Questor
T_MODE_ROWS=10

# < -----------------------------------------------------------------

# NOTE: Triggers the two main methods of the script. By Questor
f_chk_corrupted
f_del_corrupted

exit 0
```

> **[Refs.:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jcC-lYGM0k , https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=pgsql-es-ayuda@lists.postgresql.org&q=subject:%22Re%5C%3A+unexpected+chunk+number%22&o=newest&f=1
>   ,  https://raghavt.blog/fixing-up-a-corrupted-toast-table/ , 
>   https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31008/pg-dump-and-error-missing-chunk-number-0-for-toast-value
>   ,  [Postgres log file contains: missing chunk number 0 for toast value 815441 in pg_toast_2619](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47533639/3223785) , 
>   https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2324305 , 
>   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/storage-toast.html , 
>   https://www.postgresql-archive.org/pg-dump-error-td2077707.html , 
>   https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1151339 , 
>   https://oraerr.com/database/postgre/pg_dump-and-error-missing-chunk-number-0-for-toast-value/
>   ,  https://postgrespro.ru/list/thread-id/1207970 , 
>   https://newbiedba.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/postgresql-missing-chunk-0-for-toast-value-in-pg_toast/
>   ,  https://gist.github.com/supix/80f9a6111dc954cf38ee99b9dedf187a
>   **]**

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error **is** caught by the exception block.

The error you observe comes from the `DELETE` statement in the exception handler.

Comment: Unfortunately the block within "EXCEPTION" is not fired. Thanks!

Comment: If you force an error in the `SELECT file [...]` block, you can prove what I say.

Comment: I cannot prove it, because I don't have a corrupted database at hand, but you can if you add a `RAISE NOTICE` in the exception handler before the `DELETE`. If the notice is displayed, I was right.

Comment: This behavior is very strange because the exception "WHEN OTHERS THEN" catches any exception and it actually occurs. I really don't know what happens. =\

Comment: Exceptions that are thrown in the exception handler are not caught by the exception handler.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `DELETE FROM [...]` statement. I tested this hypothesis. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe that, because if you delete a row, the TOAST entries must be deleted as well, which would cause the same error.

Comment: If you change the line `DELETE FROM [...]` to this `SELECT my_id_fld INTO my_id_now FROM public.lb_file_inatives WHERE my_id=my_id_now;` and you "force" an error on the `SELECT file [...]` line, you may notice that select `SELECT my_id_fld INTO [...]` is executed perfectly. That is, the problem is that the `EXCEPTION` block is not executed. The same effect can be obtained by deleting the line `DELETE FROM [...]`.

Comment: Huh? But the `DELETE` (and your replacement `SELECT`) **is** in the exception handler, so that proves that the exception handler is executed.

Comment: The snippet `RAISE NOTICE 'CORRUPTED MY_ID - % ', my_id_now;` is not printed and therefore not executed. There is no way to explain it better.

Comment: What is the data type of `my_id`?

Comment: The "my_id" data type is "UUID". =D

Comment: Ok, then I am out of guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be useful to **post here some answers obtained in one of the official email lists of PG** ( pgsql-bugs@lists.postgresql.org, https://lists.postgresql.org/ ).

---

**Tom's Answers:**

- QUESTION

> ```
> my_database=# SELECT file INTO my_file_now FROM public.my_datatable WHERE
> ```
>
> my_id='2fdf5297-8d4a-38bc-bb26-b8a4b7ba47ec';
>       ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for toast value 3483039 in pg_toast_3473493

- ANSWER

> We've fixed a few bugs over the years that manifest in that type of
>   problem --- are you up to date on minor releases?  It's also possible
>   that reindexing that toast table would fix it.

- QUESTION

> Based on the above behavior I created the following stored procedure:
>
> ```
> ...
> my_file_now BYTEA;
> ...
> SELECT file
>     INTO my_file_now
>     FROM public.my_datatable WHERE my_id=my_id_now;
> ```
>
> QUESTION: Why is the error observed in the query not caught by the
>   "EXCEPTION" block in the stored procedure?

- ANSWER

> I think that plpgsql will not bother to dereference a TOAST pointer
>   when storing it into a local variable (although this statement is very
>   possibly version-dependent, and you didn't say what PG version you are
>   using).
>
> A more reliable way to trigger the problem is to do some computation
>   that requires the value of the field, perhaps along the lines of
>
> ```
> PERFORM md5(file) FROM public.my_datatable WHERE my_id=my_id_now;
> EXCEPTION
>     WHEN OTHERS THEN
>     RAISE NOTICE 'CORRUPTED MY_ID - % ', my_id_now;
>     DELETE FROM public.my_datatable WHERE my_id=my_id_now;
> ```
>
> I don't know that I'd give a procedure like this license to delete my
>   entire table :-(.  If you really don't care how much data survives,
>   why not just TRUNCATE the table and be done with it?  Otherwise,
>   printing the list of troublesome rows for manual review seems way more
>   prudent.

---

**David's Answers:**

- QUESTION

> Thanks for the suggestions! I found it a bit strange "pgsql" not to
>   "understand" as an exception the "ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for
>   toast value 3483039 in pg_toast_3473493"

- ANSWER

> I think Tom's point is that the function you wrote never actually
>   attempted to print out the value of the field so the error never got
>   triggered in the function.  You need to actually attempt to manipulate
>   the data to get an error.  If you did get the function to actually
>   encounter the error it should (haven't tested myself) be caught in the
>   exception handler; i.e., "A more reliable way to trigger the problem
>   is to do some computation that requires the value of the field,
>   perhaps along the lines of [query to try]".